# How to serialize form with input files?

Tags: angularjs

I have form with textarea and:

```
<input type="file" name="files" file-input="files" multiple />
```

How to serialiaze this form and send AJAX with textarea value and files using:

I tried this way:

```
$scope.send = function(data) {

            var path = $filter('sprintf')(paths.comment.send, $scope.issue.project.id, $scope.issue.campaign.id, $scope.issue.id);

            var formData = new FormData();

            angular.forEach($scope.files, function(value, key) {
                formData.append(key, value);
            });

            formData .append('body', $scope.comment.body);

            $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: path,
                    transformRequest: angular.identity,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')
                    },

                    data: formData
                })

                .then(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);

                },

                function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                });

        };
```

But it does not work

Comment: Can you explain what does your textarea keep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sending a formData object created by the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), it is important to set the content type header to `undefined`.

```
    var formData = new FormData();

    angular.forEach($scope.files, function(value, key) {
        formData.append(key, value);
    });

    formData .append('body', $scope.comment.body);

    $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: path,
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {
                //'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                //USE content type undefined
                'Content-Type': undefined,
                'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')
            },

            data: formData
        })
```

Normally the `$http` service sets the content type to `application/json`. When the content type header is `undefined`, the content type is set by the [XHR send method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send).

In this case the [XHR API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) needs to include the [encapsulation boundary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type#Content-Type_in_HTML_forms) with the content type header. It "does not work" with `formData` objects when the XHR API is forced to use a content type header without an [encapsulation boundary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type#Content-Type_in_HTML_forms).